# Rewrite all urls with .html extension except for index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following htaccess is removing the .html extension from our files fine eg:

/page1.html redirects to /page1

but we now cannot add folders as it is redirecting the /new-folder/index.html file to /new-folder/index

Is there any way around this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/ 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you `301` rule that removes `.html` to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.html[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# rewrite to dir/index.html if it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1/index.html [L]
```

This will redirect `/new-folder/index.html` to `/new-folder/` but will redirect `/new-folder/form.html` to `/new-folder/form`.

Comment: Hi thats great but I still need to modify the rewrite rule to ignore index.html? Right now it is showing a 404 for /new-folder/

Comment: No rewrite is needed for that. Just keep `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` at tops of your .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, in my case I do need it because some of the pages ie: contact-us.html are rewritten to /contact-us and they are already indexed. I know this isn't the ideal setup but it is an inherited project.

Comment: /new-folder/ works
/contact-us (contact-us.html) is still showing 404.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199503/discussion-between-tommy-arnold-and-anubhava).